# Why @Value annotation modify value initialized by <constructor-arg> attribute in Spring in Autowire Constructor mode

Tags: spring

If I am using Spring Annotation Based configuration and trying to initialize a Bean

```
 <bean id="employeeId" class="com.test.Employee">   
        <constructor-arg name="employeeId" value="50"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and initialize Java class as follows

```
   @Value("100")
        private int employeeId;
```

then after creation of bean it is returning employeeId as "100" instead of 50.

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what happens behind the scenes, when you load the spring container, first the beans are initialized by calling the constructor and then the other methods are executed.

The `@Value` is executed to set the value of `employeeId` after the execution of the constructor, therefore the value of the `employeeId` will be 100 and not 50